# How to address sessions in mixed-liner model?

Tags: mixed-model

I am performing a mixed-linear model and I am unsure how to address my sessions in this model.

The main question in my research is finding if psychological factors can predict neurofeedback success. I have 40 subjects that undergo 6 sessions of Neurofeedback training.

**My data:**

- I have the average neurofeedback success for each subject, for each session. Also for each subject and session, I have the correlation between their brain activity and the feedback they received in the session (this variable represents in a way the "group"- if they were in the test group the correlation value is high, and in the control group it's low).
- I have for each subject 4 psychological factors that were collected before they started neurofeedback training. Therefore I have one value for each subject (for all sessions!) that represents the psychological factors.

I tried a couple of models:

**The first one was a three-way interaction:**

```r
model1 <- lmer(NF_Success ~ (F1_ANH * SESS * corr) + 
                (F2_MOT * SESS * corr) + (F3_PUN * SESS * corr) + 
                (F4_MUS * SESS*corr) + (1|SUB), data = data_MIX_all)
```

The dependent variable is neurofeedback success (NF_Success). I put factors (F1_ANH, F2_MOT, F3_PUN, F4_MUS), the correlation between their brain activity and the feedback (corr), and session (SESS) as a fixed effect, while the subjects (SUB) are random.
However, I'm not sure if a three-way interaction is reasonable to use.

**The second model I tried:**

```r
model <- lmer(NF_Success ~(F1_ANH * corr) + (F2_MOT * corr) + 
             (F3_PUN * corr) + (F4_MUS *corr)+ (SESS|SUB), 
             data = data_MIX_all)
```

In this model, I put the session as a random effect and not an interaction.

I'm not sure what is the right way to address it and would appreciate any insights about which model to use.

**An extra question:**
In the results, I get for the first model only a significant main effect for F1_ANH, while in the second model, I get a significant main effect for F1_ANH and a significant interaction F1_ANH:corr. I would love your help also in interpreting these results in the manner of understanding the model- why when the session is random the interaction between F1_ANH:corr turn out to be significant?

I'm adding an example of how my dataset looks, if it helps:

```r
| SUB | SESS | NF_Sucess | corr | F1_ANH | F2_MOT | F3_PUN | F4_MUS |
| --- | --- |  ------- |-------|---| ---| ---| ---| ---|
| 1| 1 | 0.119590154|    0.868314423 | 0.5102 | 0.64539 |0.28982  |-0.40175     
| 1| 2 |  0.224365201| 0.856238894  |  0.5102 | 0.64539|0.28982|-0.40175
| 1| 3 | 0.388824392|0.75901501|0.5102|0.64539|0.28982|-0.40175
| 1| 4 |  0.073829 |0.8258684|0.5102|0.64539|0.28982|-0.40175
| 1| 5 | 0.341638878|0.802587415|0.5102|0.64539|0.28982|-0.40175
| 1| 6 |1.020422691|0.828045639|0.5102|0.64539|0.28982|-0.40175
| 2| 1 |0.007833176|0.063571708|-2.8383|1.02389|0.50746|1.55911
| 2| 2 |0.409888286|-0.043458464|-2.8383|1.02389|0.50746|1.55911
```

```
data <- structure(c(1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 1, 2, 0.119590154, 
0.224365201, 0.388824392, 0.073829, 0.341638878, 1.020422691, 
0.007833176, 0.409888286, 0.868314423, 0.856238894, 0.75901501, 
0.8258684, 0.802587415, 0.828045639, 0.063571708, -0.043458464, 
0.5102, 0.5102, 0.5102, 0.5102, 0.5102, 0.5102, -2.8383, -2.8383, 
0.64539, 0.64539, 0.64539, 0.64539, 0.64539, 0.64539, 1.02389, 
1.02389, 0.28982, 0.28982, 0.28982, 0.28982, 0.28982, 0.28982, 
0.50746, 0.50746, -0.40175, -0.40175, -0.40175, -0.40175, -0.40175, 
-0.40175, 1.55911, 1.55911), dim = c(8L, 8L), dimnames = list(
    NULL, c("SUB", "SESS", "NF_Success", "corr", "F1_ANH", "F2_MOT", 
    "F3_PUN", "F4_MUS")))
```

Comment: I would have thought you need to include session as a fixed effect if you include it as a random effect unless lmer automagically does that for you.

Comment: The session is not "important" to me per se. Only as an interaction so that maybe the psychological factors predict NF SUCCESS differently for each session. Therefore I put it either in interaction or in the other model as random because I'm not interested in putting session number as a predictor of my model. 

But, If I put it on the model as fixed would it make sense to put it also 
like this (SESS|SUB)? The model:
model17 <- lmer(NF_Success ~(F1_ANH * corr) + (F2_MOT * corr) + (F3_PUN * corr) + (F4_MUS *corr)+ SESS+ (SESS|SUB), data = data_MIX_all)

Thank you for the help!

Comment: @mdewey I thought the opposite. A variable is usually either a fixed effect or a random effect.